# Social login on Android with Feathers JS back end

Tags: android, authentication, feathersjs

I want to connect my Android and iOS app to Feathers JS back end. To authenticate users, I want to have social (Google and Facebook) logins at the client side using the respective SDKs.

Now, I want to have an authorization mechanism also in my Feathers back end, so that only authenticated users can access the data. However, I am unable to figure out how the authentication in client can be linked to the authorization in server.

I think the Token based authentication in Feathers would fit my needs, but I can't find any example of it in their documentation. Any leads / ideas are appreciated!

Comment: I faced the same problem and figure out a solution. I wrote a [Medium article](https://medium.com/@jacobgoh101/social-login-with-feathersjs-back-end-f834e5017230) to explain how. The solutions involve creating a custom PassportJs Strategy for the use case. The flow: - Obtain social token, social id and email on the client side and send it to the server. - Create a custom PassportJs strategy to validate the info sent by client. - Server sent JWT back to authorize client. The complete solution is too long to include here.